# Difference between & and and in python

Tags: python

```
year=1992

print (year%4==0 and (year%100==0 or year%400==0))

print (year%4==0 & (year%100==0 or year%400==0))
```

Why two output are not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence. Bitwise operations have higher precedence than equality comparison operator, so your bitwise operation is being computed as:

```
print (year%4 == (0 & (year%100==0 or year%400==0)))
```